# Renaming multiple file paths INSIDE a file with updated file paths

Tags: python, bash, file

I have a file called `experiments.txt` that contains arguments to a python script called `script.py`.

```
../data/20211015_08-09-50CST_raw_fold_results-mlr.csv --plot True
../data/20211115_08-15-35CST_raw_fold_results-rf.csv --plot True
```

Assume the folder structure and files is as shown below, and note that the `csv` files in `data/` are **NOT** the same as the ones in `experiments.txt`.

```
data
 |___20211117_09-10-50CST_raw_fold_results-mlr.csv
 |___20211117_09-11-35CST_raw_fold_results-rf.csv
src
 |___script.py
 |___experiments.txt
```

I would like to replace the first argument

(e.g., `../data/20211015_08-09-50CST_raw_fold_results-mlr.csv`)

for each line in `experiments.txt` with the updated data so that `experiments.txt` (or a new file is created like `experiments-2.txt`) becomes

```
..\data\20211117_09-10-50CST_raw_fold_results-mlr.csv --plot True
..\data\20211117_09-11-35CST_raw_fold_results-rf.csv --plot True
```

I know I could write a heavy-handed solution using the Python, but my solution seems suboptimal at best and really, really poorly designed at worst. **How could I perform the desired task in bash (since it would be well suited it seems to the task, but I am unsure of how)?**

```py
# This sample solution is written in `.ipynb` in the `src/` directory
import os
from pathlib import Path

cwd = os.getcwd()  # src
replacement_fnames = [file for file in os.listdir(os.path.join(cwd, '..', 'data'))]
with open('experiments.txt', 'r') as fobj:
    lines = [line.strip() for line in fobj.readlines()]

    # The replacement lines for the file `experiments-2.txt` will be
    # appended to this empty string
    write_str = ''

    for line in lines:

        # A line in the file is of the form
        # `path <SPACE> opts`, therefore splitting the line into a
        # list delimited by a space `' '` allows access to the `path`
        # by indexing 0
        space_separated_line = line.split(' ')
        cur_path = Path(space_separated_line[0])
        cur_fname = Path(cur_path).name

        # File names are separated by model name... in this case
        # `mlr` and `rf`... by splitting the file name into a list
        # delimited by `-`, then the last element of that list is the
        # name of the model
        # e.g., cur_fname = 20211015_08-09-50CST_raw_fold_results-mlr.csv
        # cur_fname.split('-') --> ['20211015_08-09-50CST_raw_fold_results', 'mlr.csv']
        cur_fname_model_name = cur_fname.split('-')[-1] 

        for replacement_fname in replacement_fnames:

            # Extract model name from the replacement fname in the same
            # fashion as done for cur_fname
            replacement_fname_model_name = replacement_fname.split('-')[-1]

            if replacement_fname_model_name == cur_fname_model_name:
                space_separated_line[0] = os.path.join(Path(cur_path).parent, replacement_fname)
                
        write_str += ' '.join(space_separated_line) + '\n'

print('Original:')
print('\n'.join(lines))
print()
print('Replaced:')
print(write_str)

with open('experiments-2.txt', 'w') as fobj:
    fobj.write(write_str)

## Output
# Original:
# ../data/20211015_08-09-50CST_raw_fold_results-mlr.csv --plot True
# ../data/20211115_08-15-35CST_raw_fold_results-rf.csv --plot True

# Replaced:
# ..\data\20211117_09-10-50CST_raw_fold_results-mlr.csv --plot True
# ..\data\20211117_09-11-35CST_raw_fold_results-rf.csv --plot True
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the filename e.g. `20211015_08-09-50CST_raw_fold_results-mlr.csv`
can be broken into the *variable* prefix `20211015_08-09-` and the fixed
substring `50CST_raw_fold_results-mlr.csv`, we can test the existing
files in the `data` directory using the fixed substring.
Then would you please try:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A map                          # associative array to map filenames
for f in ../data/*.csv; do              # find the csv filenames in the ../data dir
    f2="$(sed -E 's/.*[0-9]{8}_[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-//' <<< "$f")"
                                        # remove the variable prefix (dirname and the date)
    map[$f2]=$f                         # map the fixed substring of the filename to the fullpath
done

while read -r path opts; do             # read line of experiments.txt and break into variables
    f2="$(sed -E 's/.*[0-9]{8}_[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-//' <<< "$path")"
                                        # remove the variable prefix (dirname and the date)
    f=${map[$f2]}                       # map filename via the fixed substring
    if [[ -n $f ]]; then                # if the variable $f is not empty, the file exists
        echo "${f//\//\\} $opts"        # replace slashes with backslashes and write to "experiments-2.txt"
    fi
done < experiments.txt > experiments-2.txt
```

- In the `for f in ../data/*.csv; do` loop, assuming `f` is assigned to
  `../data/20211117_09-10-50CST_raw_fold_results-mlr.csv`, then the `sed` command `sed -E 's/.*[0-9]{8}_[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-//'` removes the prefix
  then `f2` is assigned to `50CST_raw_fold_results-mlr.csv`.
- `map[$f2]=$f` assigns the associative array (aka dictionary in python) indexed by `50CST_raw_fold_results-mlr.csv` to its full
  pathname `../data/20211117_09-10-50CST_raw_fold_results-mlr.csv`.
- In the following `while` loop, we replace the filenames using the *fixed* substring as a key to the full pathname.

**[Alternative]**
If we convert the `bash` script above to `python`, it will look like:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import glob
import re

map = {re.sub(r'.*\d{8}_\d{2}-\d{2}-', '', f) : f for f in glob.glob('../data/*.csv')}
with open('experiments.txt', 'r') as f, open('experiments-2.txt', 'w') as fw:
    for line in f:
        path, opts = line.strip().split(' ', 1)
        f2 = re.sub(r'.*\d{8}_\d{2}-\d{2}-', '', path)
        if f2 in map:
            fw.write(' '.join([map[f2], opts]).replace('/', '\\') + '\n')
```

JFYI

Comment: From the `src/` directory , I tried these commands; however, `experiments-2.txt` only contains `../data/data1-2.csv --plot True`

Comment: I have looked around a bit, it seems `sed` might be a good tool here as well? The problem I have posted is very much a toy problem, but in reality the file names in the `data` directory are only those which correspond to the updated data `20211010_raw-model_name1.csv` . Then in the `experiments.txt` the first arg might be `20200909_raw-model_name1.csv` to be replaced. Therefore, my thoughts are to iterate through the names of the updated data in the `data` directory, if the model name (delimited by '-') matches that of the line in `experiments.txt`, that line's first arg gets changed.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. But I still don't have a clue why my code does not
produce your expected result. Could you please update your question with your actual
filenames and the expected result so I can reproduce the current problem?
As you mention `sed` is an option to replace the filenames, however, I have had
decided `bash` is also good enough for the purpose with your provided examples. BR.

Comment: I have updated the question to reflect the current problem. I also have updated the sample Python solution, which I hope can illustrate exactly what I am looking for. Thank you!!

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensible update. Now I think I got it. Would you please test with the updated script? Cheers!

Comment: I tested the bash script you have provided, but unfortunately the result was similar to the last script: only the first line was written. `experiments-2.txt` now contains only `..\data\20211117_09-10-50CST_raw_fold_results-mlr.csv --plot True`. Also, thank you for providing the alternative. I will have to look more into regexes to understand the syntax.